# How to get multiple checkbox value using jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget?

Tags: jquery, select

My multiselect automatically generate the name of the checkboxes like : `name="multiselect_categorySelect` . I want to generate automatically like this : `name="multiselect_categorySelect[]` with '[]' . Im using the multiselect from [this site](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)

My code is :

```
<select  multiple="multiple" id ="categorySelect" name = "category" >     
 <option values ="1">Category 1 </option>
 <option values ="2">Category 2 </option>
 <option values ="3">Category 3 </option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#categorySelect").multiselect({
                    header: false

    });
</script>
```

What can i include in multiselect to generate the name of the checkboxes as I mentioned?

Comment: I didn't write it, but all of the js and css from the multiselect are included !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there's no option for that you'd have to modify the original source. In line 165

```
html += '<input id="' + inputID + '" name="multiselect_' + id + '" type="' + (o.multiple ? "checkbox" : "radio") + '" value="' + value + '" title="' + title + '"';
```

change

```
name="multiselect_' + id + '"
```

to

```
name="multiselect_' + id + '[]"
```

Or, if you don't want to touch the source, use the widgets create event:

```
create: function () {
    var $widget = $(this).multiselect("widget");
    var $inputs = $widget.find(".ui-multiselect-checkboxes input:checkbox");
    var newName = $inputs.first().attr("name") + "[]";
    $inputs.attr("name", newName);
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/982/

Answer (score 0):

This is a not a good answer but it works:

```
$(" label input").each(function(){
            var x = $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name")+"[]");
});
```